# error code in WordPress: {"code":0,"url":""}

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress website stopped displaying images in my portfolio. When O logged in to the CP, I see this error `{"code":0,"url":""}` in many places like: when load official wp feeds, when try to add blocks, when try to add images or edit pages.

Do you have any suggestion?
I did google it without any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try adding this to the top of your `.htaccess` file,
I had the same issue and this resolved it:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

This should help page load in the future too!
These file types will be cached in order to improve faster loading times in the future.

Hope that helps. 
Also if Yahoo is okay leave it be unless you start to get the same error.